# How do I make a random number generater from 1 to 4 in c++

Tags: c++, random, numbers, generator

I am working on getting different responses for a personal A.I system. We all know how boring it is to get the same response. So I am trying to get different responses. I have a random number generator but it only prints the number one. Here it is. What did I do wrong

```
int random_integer;
int lowest=1, highest=4;
int range=(highest-lowest)+1;
random_integer = lowest + int(range*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 4.0));
```

Comment: In general: `rand() % ( max - min + 1 ) + min`

Comment: The answer is at the duplicate link that has 309 upvotes.  The other answers given at the link was the way it was done before `<random>` in C++11 came along.